# Orbeon Oracle persistence crud.xpl

Tags: oracleforms, orbeon

I am using Orbeon Forms PE and Oracle to store data. When I am creating and publishing the forms I am able to store in Oracle. I want to edit the existing queries. I came to know all 
queries will be sitting in `curd.xpl` in `path.resources\apps\oracle`. When I had 
seen this location this folder is not there. Then to which XPL file my application is referring to execute the queries.

Another thing is I downloaded the GitHub and created the folder and placed the crud.xpl
when edit the query its not getting effected. Do I need to mention anywhere to take execute 
queries from this file?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle persistence layer](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-persistence-layer) is part of Form Runner. The resources for Form Runner are not stored directly under `WEB-INF/resources`, but inside a jar file. See [How can I changes files in Form Runner?](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/orbeon-forms-faq/faq-orbeon-form-builder#TOC-How-can-I-changes-files-in-Form-Run) for more information on how to change the code packaged in the Form Runner jar.